# Indexing is not working

Tags: index, mysql-5, index-tuning, index-statistics

Following is the table and index information for which I have the queries at the end.

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `food` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `page_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `cuisine` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `subcuisine` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `per_nr` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_parent_category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id_idx` (`id`),
  KEY `page_no_idx` (`page_no`),
  KEY `source_idx` (`source`),
  KEY `nid_idx` (`nid`),
  KEY `per_nr_idx` (`per_nr`),
  KEY `per_nr_source_category_nid_idx` (`per_nr`,`source_category`,`nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**EXPLAIN 1**

```
mysql > EXPLAIN SELECT food.nid, name, brand, cuisine, source_category, subcuisine, course, per_nr  FROM food where category is not null and  per_nr is not null and nid is not null;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | food  | ALL  | nid_idx,per_nr_idx,per_nr_source_category_nid_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 532752 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

**EXPLAIN 2**

```
mysql > EXPLAIN SELECT name, nid, brand, cuisine, type, subcuisine, course, per_nr, source, source_category FROM food where per_nr>47 and source_category='Cereal Grains and Pasta' and food.nid!=205014 and food.nid is not null;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | food  | ALL  | nid_idx,per_nr_idx,per_nr_source_category_nid_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 532752 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)
```

**Queries:**

1. **Explain 1**: As we can see the query contains column name which are indexed as well, but still explain show that the mysql was not able to identify key to make it faster.
2. **Explain 2**: I have created combined index **per_nr_source_category_nid_idx** in the same order in which the fields are available in where clause but still the mysql couldn't identify the index.

Although I have created indexes but still why system is not able to use it. This is my question in both the above queries.

**Detailed Index details**

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM food;

+-------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                       | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| food  |          1 | id_idx                         |            1 | id              | A         |      822286 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | page_no_idx                    |            1 | page_no         | A         |      822286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | source_idx                     |            1 | source          | A         |          27 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | nid_idx                        |            1 | nid             | A         |      822286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | per_nr_idx                     |            1 | per_nr          | A         |          27 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | per_nr_source_category_nid_idx |            1 | per_nr          | A         |          27 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | per_nr_source_category_nid_idx |            2 | source_category | A         |       12092 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| food  |          1 | per_nr_source_category_nid_idx |            3 | nid             | A         |      822286 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
8 rows in set (4.35 sec)
```

Comment: category in WHERE clause refers to source_category ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf: no the category is different column, I edited the table, thanks for noticing.

Comment: How many rows are there in the table?  It looks like the selectivity of the multi-column index is too low.

Answer (score 2):

The order you put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause doesn't matter. But whether the conditions are `=` or `<>` or `IS NULL` does matter in combination with the order of columns  in composite indexes. To clear this out:

```
--------- condition ----------   ----- index can be used ----   -- index search --
column = @some_constant_value          yes                        index seek
column IS NULL                         yes                        index seek

column > @some_constant_value    yes but no further columns       index scan
column < @some_constant_value    yes but no further columns       index scan
column >= @some_constant_value   yes but no further columns       index scan
column <= @some_constant_value   yes but no further columns       index scan

column <> @some_constant_value   yes but no further columns       full index scan
column IS NOT NULL               yes but no further columns       full index scan
columnA = columnB                yes if both columns are in it    full index scan
```

So, for your first query which has a condition:

```
WHERE category IS NOT NULL 
  AND per_nr IS NOT NULL 
  AND nid IS NOT NULL
```

whatever order you put the columns in the composite index, a full index scan will be needed. The optimizer, seeing that the selectivity of this operation will be very low (meaning that even after the index scan it will still have a very high percentage of the rows passing the condition and all those rows will have to be retrieved from the table, decides to do a full scan of the table. And that is probably the best way to execute the query.

For the second query which has a condition:

```
WHERE per_nr > 47 
  AND source_category = 'Cereal Grains and Pasta' 
  AND food.nid <> 205014 
  AND food.nid IS NOT NULL
```

we'll get rid of the redundant `food.nid IS NOT NULL` (if it is different than `205014`, it cannot be `NULL` anyway) and we'll order the conditions according to the above chart:

```
WHERE source_category = 'Cereal Grains and Pasta' 
  AND per_nr > 47 
  AND nid <> 205014
```

This gives us a very useful hint about how to create the composite index:

```
(source_category)               : good index, it will be used to efficiently (index seek)
                                         narrow the search to rows 
                                         with 'Cereal Grains and Pasta' only
(source_category, per_nr)       : even better, it will be used to efficiently narrow the
                                         search to rows with 'Cereal Grains and Pasta' 
                                         and per_nr > 47. Then these rows will be read 
                                         from the table and the rows that have 
                                         (nid = 205014 or nid IS NULL) will be excluded 
(source_category, per_nr) INCLUDE (nid)
                                : even more better than the above index,
                                         it will also exclude the rows that have 
                                         (nid = 205014 or nid IS NULL) using the index
   -- !! --   Unfortunately, MySQL has not (yet) implemented `INCLUDE` indexes, 
   -- !! --       so the only improvement can be
(source_category, per_nr, nid)  : slightly better than the 2nd index,
                                         it will also exclude the rows that have 
                                         (nid = 205014 or nid IS NULL) using the index
```

So, add the 4th (or the 2nd) index:

```
ALTER TABLE food
  ADD INDEX source_category__per_nr__nid__IX   -- choose a name for the index
    (source_category, per_nr, nid) ;
```

if you want the second query to be executed efficiently:

```
SELECT name, nid, brand, cuisine, type, subcuisine, 
       course, per_nr, source, source_category 
FROM food 
WHERE per_nr > 47 
  AND source_category = 'Cereal Grains and Pasta' 
  AND nid <> 205014 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use null checks like that with indexes.  Further individual single column indexes will cannot be "combined" with your type of query (e.g. a bunch of ANDs;  there is some merge optimization that can be done for ORs though).

Instead of null could that be represented by either a 0 or empty string as appropriate.  (This of course requires those not be possible values for various columns).

Creating a composite index like

```
KEY `per_nr_idx` (`category`,`per_nr`,`id`)
```

would lend itself well to a

```
where category='' and per_nr=0 and id=0
```

clause.

Something to keep in mind with all indexes is the query optimizer determines the where clause would result in examining a significant portion of the total record space it will do a full table scan anyway.